# Add Upload Field with Preview on Review Admin Form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, review

I am currently working on the reviews module where I added a multiple file upload on the review form. I was able to add the field in storefront and create a custom table for the multiple review image saving and was able to make it work. The remaining issue is how do I add an upload field (preferably with preview) for both add and edit review form in admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can create file-uploader element in your custom admin form and you can add and edit data from there

You can follow this [link](https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-upload-image-or-file-in-custom-module-using-ui-component-in-magento-2/)

Hope this will work for you